# Move all files of a given type from a directory to another directory, but keep directory hierarchy (see explanation)

Tags: bash, shell

So, I want to move all .xml from one directory (with sub-directories) to a new directory; however, if files are in sub-directories I want them to remain in sub-directories.  Basically, I have a bunch of files that are already categorized and I only want a subset of them, but I still need them to stay separated.  I wrote this simple command, which will go through all .xml files in my cwd and its sub-directories, but this puts everything into a single directory:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec mv {} ~/Desktop/test/ \;
```

I don't know how to create the new sub-directories through this command/send each file to its respective new location.  I understand that I can do this through perl or some other language, but I'd like to be able to do it through terminal commands (I'm trying to learn how to toy with bash).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `tar` to copy files with directory structure:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -print0 |
tar -cf - --null -T- |
tar -C ~/Desktop/test/ -xf -
```

Alternatively, you can use `cp` with the option `--parents`:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec cp -a -t ~/Desktop/test/ --parents {} +
```

Comment: Pretty sure the `-f -` is redundant, `tar` uses stdin/stdout by default

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Thanks, I have fixed the typos in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p ~/Desktop/`dirname "{}"`; mv "{}" ~/Desktop/`dirname "{}"`' \;
```

Comment: The original question was about moving files and this answer does exactly that. The other answers all deal with copying files not moving! Anyway, I needed to move my movies out of my pictures folders keeping the same hierarchy and this solved that problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For some situations i like the `cpio` command

```
any_command_what_produces_relative_path_names | cpio -pamVd /new/parent/dir
```

for example:

```
find . -name \*.xml -print0 | cpio -pamvd0 /new/parent/dir
```

or with filtering the output of the find

```
find . -name \*.xml -print0 |\
  grep -zP 'only_some_of_them' |\
  cpio -pamvd0 /new/parent/dir
```

or only those, what contains the string "blabla"

```
find . -name \*.xml -print0 |\
  xargs -0 grep -zl "blabla" |\
  cpio -pamvd0 /new/parent/dir
```